# DKIM settings for domain with 302 redirect

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, dkim

I have 2 domains. I'll call them example.com and example2.com.

My website is currently at example.com but one day will probably be moved to example2.com.

Currently, example2.com has these two CloudFlare page rules:

```
Page Rules    
1   www.example2.com/*
Forwarding URL: (Status Code: 301 - Permanent Redirect, Url: https://example2.com/$1)   
2   example2.com/*
Forwarding URL: (Status Code: 302 - Temporary Redirect, Url: https://example.com/$1)
```

That way, if anyone visits any page of example2.com, they get immediately bounced to where my site currently is (at example.com).

All of that works well, but here is the tricky part.

I now want to start sending emails from example2.com. (Specifically, I want my FreshDesk.com account to be allowed to send emails from example2.com.)

I've added FreshDesk's 4 recommended CNAME settings to my CloudFlare DNS setup in both example.com and example2.com.

But DKIM verification has failed.

I then was curious enough to temporarily disable the CloudFlare page rules such that example2.com shows the contents of example.com but without the redirect (i.e. the URL remains example2.com in the browser).

DKIM verification still failed. So maybe the 302 redirect is irrelevant.

Any ideas on how to accomplish what I'm hoping for?

Comment: DKIM key is put into a TXT field, not a CNAME...

Comment: @Anubioz Not according to the docs at https://support.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/223779-digitally-sign-emails-with-dkim-

Comment: Tell them their docs suck https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6376#section-7.5